# How to perform raw PostGIS queries with includes using sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, postgis

Trying to use sequelize's built in ORM convenience include syntax with a raw PostGIS query.

This call correctly joins the related promotionImage and category tables just as I need it, but it doesn't geo query my database like I need it to:

```
  promotion.findAll({
    include: [{
      model: promotionImage
    }, {
      model: category
    }]
  }).then(promoters => {
    res.json(promoters)
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('ERROR: ', err)
  })
```

On the other hand, this query correctly finds the "promotions" within the provided lat/lng bounds, but it does not correctly join the associated promotionImage and category tables:

```
    const query = '\
      SELECT * \
      FROM "promotions" \
      WHERE "promotions"."location" && ST_MakeEnvelope(:southWestLng, :southWestLat, :northEastLng, :northEastLat)'
    replacements = {
      southWestLng, 
      southWestLat, 
      northEastLng, 
      northEastLat
    }

  db.sequelize.query(query, {
    replacements,
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
    model: promotion,
    include: [{
      model: promotionImage
    }, {
      model: category
    }]
  }).then(promoters => {
    res.json(promoters)
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('ERROR: ', err)
  })
```

Is there a way to both query using the `ST_MakeEnvelope` syntax and include the data from the other models with sequelize and postGIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sequelize.query()` doesn't support `include`, you can use `Sequelize.fn()` with `findAll`

```
 promotion.findAll({
    where: {
       location: {
           $overlap: db.sequelize.fn('ST_MakeEnvelope', southWestLng, southWestLat, northEastLng, northEastLat)
       }
    },
    include: [{
      model: promotionImage
    }, {
      model: category
    }]
  }).then(promoters => {
    res.json(promoters)
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('ERROR: ', err)
  })
```

Comment: It looks like your answer got me really close. But it's not returning any results. I think the issue is that the postGIS query is not supposed to have an `=` sign, but instead an `&&`. So your answer formats the query: `WHERE "promotion"."location" = ST_MakeEnvelope(...` when it's supposed to be: `WHERE "promotions"."location" && ST_MakeEnvelope(...`